# Unable to select my gridview row of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've added a gridview into my asp.net webapp. I also added a select button in the gridview. However, when i click the select button in the gridview, i receive this error

[image]

Here is my gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvnric" runat="server"  Align="Center" Width="30%" 
        BackColor="#CCCCCC" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvnric_Sorting" 
        BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" 
        CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvnric_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="True" 
        PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gvnric_PageIndexChanging">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" /> 
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

This format of my gridview code is working out fine for my other page but not for my current one. Why is this so?

This is how i bind my data in the gridview with loadgrid. I uses this loadgrid for the paging

```
private void LoadGrid()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        //conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI";
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select nric as [NRIC] from MemberAccount Where status = 'unverified'", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

        gvnric.DataSource = ds.Copy();
        gvnric.DataBind();

        conn.Close();

    }
```

I also re-bind it using DataBindByDataSet. This time it is for gridview sorting

```
private DataTable DataBindByDataSet()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        //conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI";
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select nric as [NRIC] from MemberAccount Where status = 'unverified'", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

All my other pages also uses the 2 different way of binding which assist in the paging and sorting but just not for this gridview. The binding codes are actually the same for both loadgrid and databindbydataset but each have different uses.
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025043/asp-net-c-unable-to-select-in-gridview-when-i-press-the-select-button-nothing) which asked similiar question but it doesn't help.

Comment: From my recollection, the `Select$0` means it is trying to select row zero, which I am not sure how a select button would show without any other data, are there rows in the grid?

Comment: Yes. There's data in the row though. Otherwise i wont be able to select and prompt the error though.

Comment: try with `gvnric.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Comment: I've just realized my problem and sorry for using up your time. Thanks to @Samiey Mehdi, i realized my selectedindex code are wrong which lead me to this error. Thank you for your time to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedIndexChanged code of GridView is wrong to detect row.

Comment: may i ask what exactly is keyfield in the gridview?

Comment: how to you fill gridview.

Comment: i did not bind it via sqldatasource. i do it via the loadgrid and databindbydataset.

Comment: can you share binding of gridview and SelectedIndexChanged code

Comment: Hey, thanks for your idea. I realized my selectedindex code is totally wrong. The gridview was able to bind the data but i insert the wrong selectedindex code which causes the gridview not to understand the row being selected. Sorry for wasting your time though